# How to find RDS public IP. - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a command to connect the RDS instance, but I don’t know where this public IP address comes from. Where I can get the public IP address?
I took over a project. There is a RDS connection.  Recently the connection get a time-out issue. The connection command is like this:

```
ssh -L 3310:dev.instid.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 ec2-user@198.51.100.11
```

(this IP is not the real IP address, for some security restrictions, I cannot give a real IP at here.)

> sh: connect to host 198.51.100.11 port 22: Operation timed out

I have checked the RDS Publicly accessible is NO. I think it should be a security group issue. However, I don’t know where is this IP (198.51.100.11) coming from and what security group attached to this IP.

How I can find out where this IP (198.51.100.11) is configured?

If I want config a RDS with SSH connection, how I can do it?

Comment: RDS stands for Remote Desktop Server, but you're having an issue with SSH (port 22)

Comment: that IP address seems to be assigned to "DoD Network Information Center" and has a military contact

Comment: Sorry, @Jaromanda X. The IP is not a real IP address. I forget to let you know that. Do you know how to config a RDS with SSH connection?

Comment: the issue you are having is not with RDS since your ssh failed, so, first, your ssh has to connect - as for "fake" IP address, it's not fake, it's just not the one you use ... and saying `How I can find out where this IP (11.110.116.11) is configured?` only serves to confuse the matter, since that IP address is a real PUBLIC one

Comment: lets put this in perspective, there are literally billions of IP addresses, you've posted one that is NOT the one you actually having an issue with, and you somehow want someone to tell you where some unknown IP address "is configured"

Answer (score 2):

When "RDS Publicly accessible" is set to "No" the RDS instance doesn't have a public IP, and isn't accessible from the internet. It has a private IP address and is accessible within the VPC it's deployed to.

Generally you shouldn't address an RDS instance by IP address. If something happens to the hardware, or it swaps to the other instance in a multi-AZ setup, the IP will change. You can connect using the domain name.

I doubt you can ssh to an RDS instance, though I've never tried. RDS is a managed service, you don't have OS access.

Suggest you close this question and accept the best answer, then create another question to tell us what you're trying to achieve rather than ask a detailed technical question of how you think you might achieve something.

I assume you want to configure the database in some way. That's usually done with [option groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithOptionGroups.html) or [parameters groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html) with RDS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out how the EC2 instance of the jump host has been provisioned. Find out the person who has access to the AWS control panel and who can see the EC2 instance information.